# Going to Another Page - React using button and Link

Tags: reactjs, button, router

i'm trying to go to another page using a button but pages don't change at all, and I'm using Link and Router from Router-DOM I'm using this code:

```html
<Link to="/page2">
  <button type="button" price={data.item}>Page 2</button> 
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error messages you get? Can you provide a sandbox replicate your issue?
Import Link from `react-router-dom` and wrap your app with `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: alright I did as you said, and fixed it, but pages dont change, still in my main page